# Scala: Why mapValues produces a view and is there any stable alternatives?

Tags: scala, dictionary

Just now I am surprised to learn that `mapValues` produces a view. The consequence is shown in the following example:

```
case class thing(id: Int)
val rand = new java.util.Random
val distribution = Map(thing(0) -> 0.5, thing(1) -> 0.5)
val perturbed = distribution mapValues { _ + 0.1 * rand.nextGaussian }
val sumProbs = perturbed.map{_._2}.sum
val newDistribution = perturbed mapValues { _ / sumProbs }
```

The idea is that I have a distribution, which is perturbed with some randomness then I renormalize it. The code actually fails in its original intention: since `mapValues` produces a `view`, `_ + 0.1 * rand.nextGaussian` is always re-evaluated whenever `perturbed` is used.

I am now doing something like `distribution map { case (s, p) => (s, p + 0.1 * rand.nextGaussian) }`, but that's just a little bit verbose. So the purpose of this question is:

1. Remind people who are unaware of this fact.
2. Look for reasons why they make `mapValues` output `view`s.
3. Whether there is an alternative method that produces concrete `Map`.
4. Are there any other commonly-used collection methods that have this trap.

Thanks.

Comment: OMG there is another place that I use `mapValues`, which is the reason why it runs so slow sometimes...

Comment: I've been bitten by this, too.

Comment: Today I stepped into this trap too.

Comment: Just got bitten by this today!

Comment: I know about this behavior and I _still_ fall into this trap and even worse, it's excruciating to debug.

Comment: I just got bitten by this as I was creating mutable objects in mapValues and I was confused why they aren't updating

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There's a ticket about this, [SI-4776](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4776) (by YT).

The commit that introduces it has this to say:

> Following a suggestion of jrudolph, made `filterKeys` and `mapValues`
>   transform abstract maps, and duplicated functionality for immutable
>   maps. Moved `transform` and `filterNot` from immutable to general maps.
>   Review by phaller.

I have not been able to find the original suggestion by jrudolph, but I assume it was done to make `mapValues` more efficient. Give the question, that may come as a surprise, but `mapValues` *is* more efficient if you are not likely to iterate over the values more than once.

As a work-around, one can do `mapValues(...).view.force` to produce a new `Map`.

Comment: nice, but still I wonder why mapValues doesn't return the view directly to make that more explicit?

Comment: @AloisCochard Yeah that's a good point. It's much better if return type is `view` so we are alerted what is going on there...

Comment: @AloisCochard As you can see in the ticket, that's precisely what I was asking for. It would have the further benefit of making a `force` method directly available.

Comment: I don't see the reasoning behind this decision. Using a view would improve performance only if the number of invocations (of existing keys) is less than the number of entries; from my experience, this is hardly the case in most scenarios. Views have other advantages if the underlying data is mutable (see SQL), which is less preferable in Scala as it goes against the functional approach.

Answer (score 11):

The scala doc say:

> a map view which maps every `key` of this map to `f(this(key))`. The resulting map wraps the original map without copying any elements.

So this should be expected, but this scares me a lot, I'll have to review bunch of code tomorrow. I wasn't expecting a behavior like that :-(

Just an other workaround:

You can call `toSeq` to get a copy, and if you need it back to map `toMap`, but this unnecessary create objects, and have a performance implication over using `map`

One can relatively easy write, a `mapValues` which doesn't create a view, I'll do it tomorrow and post the code here if no one do it before me ;)

**EDIT:**

I found an easy way to 'force' the view, use '.map(identity)' after mapValues (so no need of implementing a specific function):

```
scala> val xs = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
xs: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2)

scala> val ys = xs.mapValues(_ + Random.nextInt).map(identity)
ys: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(a -> 1315230132, b -> 1614948101)

scala> ys
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Int] = Map(a -> 1315230132, b -> 1614948101)
```

It's a shame the type returned isn't actually a view! othewise one would have been able to call 'force' ...

Comment: running with Scala `2.12.0-M3`, it's not clear to me what `map(identity)` buys you: `Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2).mapValues(_ + Random.nextInt)` returns `scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1496073565, b -> -1842623900)`.

Could you please elaborate? I *think* that the potential problem of `mapValues` is that it lazily evaluates values, but I'm not sure. Thanks

Comment: this is crazily surprising. how can view's map returns a concrete map instead of a view? this is beyond inconsistency. this is an entire lack of consideration. confirm from the source code that this thing still exists in 2.12.

Answer (score 1):

Is better(and deprecated) in scala 2.13, now returns a MapView:
[API Doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#mapValues[W](f:V=%3EW):scala.collection.MapView[K,W])