# FlatmapValues on Map

Tags: scala, set, grouping, flatmap

Given a `Seq` of tuples like:

```
Seq(
  ("a",Set(1,2)),
  ("a",Set(2,3)),
  ("b",Set(4,6)),
  ("b",Set(5,6))
)
```

I would like to `groupBy` and then `flatMap` the values to obtain something like:

```
Map(
  b -> Set(4, 6, 5), 
  a -> Set(1, 2, 3)
)
```

My first implementation is:

```
Seq(
  ("a" -> Set(1,2)),
  ("a" -> Set(2,3)),
  ("b" -> Set(4,6)),
  ("b" -> Set(5,6))
) groupBy (_._1) mapValues (_ map (_._2)) mapValues (_.flatten.toSet)
```

I was wondering if there was a more efficient and maybe simpler way to achieve that result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track, but you can simplify a bit by using a single `mapValues` and combining the `map` and `flatten`:

```
val r = Seq(
  ("a" -> Set(1,2)),
  ("a" -> Set(2,3)),
  ("b" -> Set(4,6)),
  ("b" -> Set(5,6))
).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.flatMap(_._2).toSet)
```

I actually find this a lot more readable than the `foldLeft` version (but note that `mapValues` returns [a non-strict collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14883167/334519), which may or may not be what you want).

Answer (score 4):

I would use foldLeft, I think it's more readable, you can avoid groupBy

```
val r = Seq(
    ("a",Set(1,2)),
    ("a",Set(2,3)),
    ("b",Set(4,6)),
    ("b",Set(5,6))
  ).foldLeft(Map[String, Set[Int]]()){
    case (seed,(k,v)) => {
      seed.updated(k,v ++ seed.getOrElse(k,Set[Int]()))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@grotrianster answer could be refined using the Semigroup binary operation `|+|` of Set and Map:

```
import scalaz.syntax.semigroup._
import scalaz.std.map._
import scalaz.std.set._

Seq(
  ("a",Set(1,2)),
  ("a",Set(2,3)),
  ("b",Set(4,6)),
  ("b",Set(5,6))
).foldLeft(Map[String, Set[Int]]()){case (seed, (k, v)) => seed |+| Map(k -> v)}
```

Using `reduce` instead of `fold`:

```
Seq(
  ("a", Set(1, 2)),
  ("a", Set(2, 3)),
  ("b", Set(4, 6)),
  ("b", Set(5, 6))
).map(Map(_)).reduce({_ |+| _})
```

Treating `Set` and `Map` as Monoids:

```
Seq(
  ("a", Set(1, 2)),
  ("a", Set(2, 3)),
  ("b", Set(4, 6)),
  ("b", Set(5, 6))
).map(Map(_)).toList.suml
```