# Twitter Finagle open too many files

Tags: scala, rpc, finagle, twitter-finagle

I use Twitter-Finagle create a server. In each RPC function of the server, Just use a Finagle client to call another server's RPC. like this:

```
def rpc() = {
  // finagleClient is created in a std way according to Finagle's Doc:
  // val client = Thrift.newIface[Hello.FutureIface]("localhost:8080")
  // http://twitter.github.io/finagle/guide/Protocols.html#thrift-and-scrooge
  //
  val f: Future[xx] = finagleClient.otherRpc()
  f onSuccess { // do something }
  f onFailure { // handle exception }
}
```

But, not too long, error happens:

```
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector: Failed to accept a connection
java.io.IOException: open too many files
```

And, I use `lsof -p` and find that there are too many connections to another server(about 5000 connections!). I want to know how does it happen? Is there anything I missed.

================ problem solved =============

plz refer to [Scala: Why mapValues produces a view and is there any stable alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882642/scala-why-mapvalues-produces-a-view-and-is-there-any-stable-alternatives),
Map's mapValue method maybe tricky

```
val resultIsAView = m.mapValue(mapFunction)
```

the function `mapFunction` will be re-evaluated every time the result view `resultIsAView` be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm that you only create one `finagleClient`, and not one for every request you receive? (i.e. `Thrift.newIface` should be outside of the `rpc` method).

Other potential cause, you may have only one client, but the `otherRpc` backend never responds, so your server creates a new connection for every request (because the previous one is still "in use").

Comment: Thanks! Steve. I confirm that only one finagleClient is created. Maybe `otherRpc` server no response is the cause. Is there any way to config RPC timeout? I think if I set the RPC timeout shorter, then no many additional connections are created.

Comment: You can do something like: `finagleClient.otherRpc().within(50.milliseconds)` for adding a timeout to the call