# Scala mapValues() type mismatch

Tags: scala

I have an assignment in Scala, so far, so good. Everything compiles except this:

```
@transient val aggs = msgs.transform { rdd => 
                                      val ts =  rdd.map(quote => quote.ts).max()  /// maximum of timestamp in the rdd
                                      rdd.map{ q => 
                                         ((q.symbol,q.ts),(q.price,ts))         /// ((String, Long), (Double, Long)) structure
                                       }
                                      }
                          .reduceByKey{ (x,y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2) }   // returns (Double, Long)
                          .mapValues( (x: Double,y: Long) => (y.toDouble / x.toDouble) ) // (Double, Long) => (Double)
                          .map{ case ((s,t),v) => (s,t,v)}
```

The piece I'm stuck on is the anonymous function in mapValues()

> :95: error: type mismatch;
>
> found   : (Double, Long) => Double
>
> required: ((Double, Long)) => ?

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: I think maybe because in `mapValues` you gave a specific case for your input, but what does it returns if it's the default case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You provided a function with two arguments, one `Double` and one `Long`, instead of a function with one argument - a tuple `(Double, Long)`. If you need a tuple as an argument, use

```
.mapValues { case (x: Double,y: Long) => whatever }
```

Note that you need to surround the `case` into `{}` instead of `()`.

Comment: You don't need double parentheses, however.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to slouc's answer:
You can use untupeld

```
import Function.untupled

Map.empty mapValues untupled myMethodWithMultipleArguments
```

Anyway, beware of mapValues, because it just creates a [view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882642/scala-why-mapvalues-produces-a-view-and-is-there-any-stable-alternatives).