# Scala Sum of Values of a Map

Tags: scala

New to scala .. I wanted to calculate the sum of all elements in List which is a value of a map.

```
case class Test(shareClass:String, noOfShares:Long){}

val list = new Test("a", 10)::new Test("b",20)::new Test("a",30)::new Test("b", 5)::Nil
```

I wanted to creates a Map of
a -> 40
b -> 25

I understand I can use group by on the list which will give me a list of test values, but I am not sure how to operate on that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `groupBy` creates a `Map` where the values are a list of all matching objects:

```
scala> list.groupBy(_.shareClass)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Test]] = Map(b -> List(Test(b,20), Test(b,5)), a -> List(Test(a,10), Test(a,30)))
```

From there you can use `mapValues` to transform the values of the map, first selecting the `noOfShares` attribute and then `sum` these:

```
scala> list.groupBy(_.shareClass).mapValues(_.map(_.noOfShares).sum)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Long] = Map(b -> 25, a -> 40)
```

Note that [`mapValues` only creates a view on the original `Map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882642/scala-why-mapvalues-produces-a-view-and-is-there-any-stable-alternatives), this means the `_.map(_.noOfShares).sum`-part is applied *every time* the result is accessed (even when assigning it to a `val` before). To get a plain `Map` with only the result, you can call `view.force` on it:

```
scala> list.groupBy(_.shareClass).mapValues(_.map(_.noOfShares).sum).view.force
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Long] = Map(b -> 25, a -> 40)
```

Comment: Note that the `Map` created by `mapValues` recalculates values on each access: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882642/scala-why-mapvalues-produces-a-view-and-is-there-any-stable-alternatives

Comment: Thank you @AlexeyRomanov! I didn't know that! I added it it the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go.

```
case class Test(shareClass: String, noOfShares: Long) {}

val list = new Test("a", 10) :: new Test("b", 20) :: new Test("a", 30) :: new Test("b", 5) :: Nil

val list2 = list.groupBy((_.shareClass))
  .map({ case (a, b) => (a, b.map(_.noOfShares).sum) })

println((list2)) // Map(b -> 25, a -> 40)
```

Comment: I like the use of `case (a,b)` to avoid `test._1, test._2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
case class Test(shareClass: String, noOfShares: Long) {}

  val list = Test("a", 10) :: Test("b", 20) :: Test("a", 30) :: Test("b", 5) :: Nil

  println(list.groupBy(_.shareClass).map(test => (test._1 -> test._2.foldLeft(0L)((o, n) => o + n.noOfShares))))
```

first, you create groups with groupBy like this:

```
Map(b -> List(Test(b,20), Test(b,5)), a -> List(Test(a,10), Test(a,30)))
```

after that you convert the element's values to the sum of Test's noOfShares