# Mockito verify fails with "TooManyActualInvocations" for method with a default parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, verify

In below code, Mockito verify doesn't works as expected on scala methods with default parameter but works fine on methods with no default parameters.

```
package verifyMethods

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.Mockito.times
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.Matchers.be
import org.scalatest.Matchers.convertToAnyShouldWrapper
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar

trait SUT {

  def someMethod( bool: Boolean ): Int = if ( bool ) 4 else 5

  def someMethodWithDefaultParameter( bool: Boolean, i: Int = 5 ): Int = if ( bool ) 4 else i
}

@RunWith( classOf[JUnitRunner] )
class VerifyMethodWithDefaultParameter extends FlatSpec with MockitoSugar with SUT {

  "mockito verify method" should "pass" in {
    val sutMock = mock[SUT]
    Mockito.when( sutMock.someMethod( true ) ).thenReturn( 4, 6 )

    val result1 = sutMock.someMethod( true )
    result1 should be( 4 )

    val result2 = sutMock.someMethod( true )
    result2 should be( 6 )

    Mockito.verify( sutMock, times( 2 ) ).someMethod( true )
  }
  //this test fails with assertion error 
  "mockito verify method with default parameter" should "pass" in {
    val sutMock = mock[SUT]
    Mockito.when( sutMock.someMethodWithDefaultParameter( true ) ).thenReturn( 4, 6 )

    val result1 = sutMock.someMethodWithDefaultParameter( true )
    result1 should be( 4 )

    val result2 = sutMock.someMethodWithDefaultParameter( true )
    result2 should be( 6 )

    Mockito.verify( sutMock, times( 2 ) ).someMethodWithDefaultParameter( true )
  }
}
```

Please suggest, what i am doing wrong in the second test.

---

**Edit 1:** @Som
Please find below stacktrace for above test class :-

```
Run starting. Expected test count is: 2
VerifyMethodWithDefaultParameter:
mockito verify method
- should pass
mockito verify method with default parameter
- should pass *** FAILED ***
  org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: sUT.someMethodWithDefaultParameter$default$2();
Wanted 2 times:
-> at zeither.VerifyMethodWithDefaultParameter$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(VerifyMethodWithDefaultParameter.scala:37)
But was 3 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at zeither.VerifyMethodWithDefaultParameter$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(VerifyMethodWithDefaultParameter.scala:34)
  ...
Run completed in 414 milliseconds.
Total number of tests run: 2
Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 1, failed 1, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
*** 1 TEST FAILED ***
```

---

**Edit 2 : @Mifeet**

As suggested, if i pass 0 for default int parameter test passes, but below test case is not passing with the suggested aprroach :-

```
  "mockito verify method with default parameter" should "pass" in {
    val sutMock = mock[SUT]
    Mockito.when( sutMock.someMethodWithDefaultParameter( true, 0 ) ).thenReturn( 14 )
    Mockito.when( sutMock.someMethodWithDefaultParameter( false, 0 ) ).thenReturn( 16 )
    val result1 = sutMock.someMethodWithDefaultParameter( true )
    result1 should be( 14 )

    val result2 = sutMock.someMethodWithDefaultParameter( false )
    result2 should be( 16 )

    Mockito.verify( sutMock, times( 1 ) ).someMethodWithDefaultParameter( true )
    Mockito.verify( sutMock, times( 1 ) ).someMethodWithDefaultParameter( false )
  }
```

Please find below stacktrace :-

```
mockito verify method with default parameter
- should pass *** FAILED ***
  org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: sUT.someMethodWithDefaultParameter$default$2();
Wanted 1 time:
-> at zeither.VerifyMethodWithDefaultParameter$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(VerifyMethodWithDefaultParameter.scala:38)
But was 2 times. Undesired invocation:
-> at zeither.VerifyMethodWithDefaultParameter$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(VerifyMethodWithDefaultParameter.scala:35)
  ...
```

Your opinion on other existing mocking libraries like PowerMock, ScalaMock is highly appreciated, if they can provide a neat solution for such cases, as i am open to use any mocking library in my project.

Comment: Please be clear about what you "expect" and what you are seeing.

Comment: See my updated answer. Sometimes you just need to get your hands dirty before you drown in bending frameworks for something they weren't designed for.

Answer (score 5):

For brevity, I will use `withDefaultParam()` instead of `someMethodWithDefaultParameter()`.

**How default parameters are translated to bytecode:**
To understand why the test fails, we must first look at how methods with default parameters are translated to Java equivalent/bytecode. 
Your method `withDefaultParam()` will be translated to two methods:

- `withDefaultParam` - this method accepts both parameters and does contains the actual implementation
- `withDefaultParam$default$2` - returns the default value of the second parameter (i.e. `i`)

When you call, e.g., `withDefaultParam(true)`, it will be translated to  invocation of `withDefaultParam$default$2` to get the default parameter value, followed by an invocation of `withDefaultParam`. You can check out the bytecode below.

**What's wrong with your test:** What Mockito is complaining about is an extra invocation of `withDefaultParam$default$2`. This is because the compiler inserts an extra call to this method right before your `Mockito.when(...)` to fill in the default. Therefore this method is invoked three times and `times(2)` assertion fails.

**How to fix it:** Your test will pass if you initialize your mock with:

```
Mockito.when(sutMock.withDefaultParam(true, 0)).thenReturn(4, 6)
```

This is strange, you may ask, why should I pass `0` for the default parameter instead of `5`? It turns out that Mockito mocks the `withDefaultParam$default$2` method too using the default `Answers.RETURNS_DEFAULTS` setting. Because `0` is the default value for `int`, *all invocations in your code actually pass `0` instead of `5`* as the second argument to `withDefaultParam()`.

**How to force the correct default value for parameter**: If you wanted your test to use `5` as the default value, you could make your test pass with something like this:

```
class SUTImpl extends SUT
val sutMock = mock[SUTImpl](Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)
Mockito.when(sutMock.withDefaultParam(true, 5)).thenReturn(4, 6)
```

In my opinion, though, this is exactly where Mockito stops being useful and becomes a burden. What we would do in our team is write a custom test implementation of `SUT` without Mockito. It doesn't cause any surprising pitfalls like above, you can implement custom assertion logic, and, most importantly, it can be reused among tests.

**Update - how I would solve it:** I don't think using a mocking library really gives you any advantage in this case. It's less pain to code your own mock. This is how I would go about it:

```
class SUTMock(results: Map[Boolean, Seq[Int]]) extends SUT {
  private val remainingResults = results.mapValues(_.iterator).view.force // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14883167 for why we need .view.force

  override def someMethodWithDefaultParameter(bool: Boolean, i: Int): Int = remainingResults(bool).next()

  def assertNoRemainingInvocations() = remainingResults.foreach {
    case (bool, remaining) => assert(remaining.isEmpty, s"remaining invocations for parameter $bool: ${remaining.toTraversable}")
  }
}
```

A test could then look like this:

```
"mockito verify method with default parameter" should "pass" in {
    val sutMock = new SUTMock(Map(true -> Seq(14, 15), false -> Seq(16)))
    sutMock.someMethodWithDefaultParameter(true) should be(14)
    sutMock.someMethodWithDefaultParameter(true) should be(15)

    sutMock.someMethodWithDefaultParameter(false) should be(16)

    sutMock.assertNoRemainingInvocations()
  }
```

This does all you need - provides required return values, blows up on too many or too few invocations. It can be reused. This is a stupid simplified example, but in a practical scenario, you should think about your business logic rather than  method invocations. If SUT was a mock for message broker, e.g., you could have a method `allMessagesProcessed()` instead of `assertNoRemainingInvocations()`, or even define more complex asserts.

---

Assume we have a variable `val sut:SUT`, here is the bytecode of calling `withDefaultParam(true)`:

```
ALOAD 1  # load sut on stack
ICONST_1 # load true on stack
ALOAD 1  # load sut on stack
INVOKEINTERFACE SUT.withDefaultParam$default$2 ()I # call method which returns the value of the default parameter and leave result on stack
INVOKEINTERFACE SUT.withDefaultParam (ZI)I         # call the actual implementation
```