# Remove options for Map's List

Tags: scala

I have a map of type:

```
Map[Int, Seq[Option[User]]]
```

I want to transform this to:

```
Map[Int, Seq[User]]
```

I just want to remove any Option[User] from the Seq.

Comment: And what do you want to do with items that are `None` that may exist in any of these sequences?

Comment: @TzachZohar I want to remove the key from the map.

Comment: If there exists a single element in the sequence that is None you want to remove the key?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov sorry, I want to remove the item from the Seq, not remove the key.

Answer (score 7):

Simple Seq#flatten does the magic:

```
scala> Map(1 -> Seq(Option(1),None, Option(3),None), 2 -> Seq(None))
res1: Map[Int,Seq[Option[Int]]] = 
   Map(1 -> List(Some(1), None, Some(3), None), 2 -> List(None))

scala> res1.mapValues(_.flatten)
res2: Map[Int,Seq[Int]] = Map(1 -> List(1, 3), 2 -> List())
```

Comment: Just remember that mapValues works counterintuitvely, by facading the orignal map rather than creating a new one. If this is a problem, you'd need: res1.map {case(k,v) -> k, v.flatten}

Comment: what? "Counterintuitively" why? "by facading the orignal map rather than creating a new one" What number 2. So give me an example where this is observable.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882642/scala-why-mapvalues-produces-a-view-and-is-there-any-stable-alternatives

Answer (score 0):

```
yourMap.map({ case (key, seq) => { 
    (key, seq.filter(uOpt => !uOpt.isEmpty).map(_.get)) 
} })
```

Or,

```
val newMap = for {
  (key, seq) <- yourMap
  newSeq = for {
    userOpt <- seq
    if !userOpt.isEmpty
  } yield userOpt.get
} yield (key -> newSeq)
```

Comment: Wow,, compare that to `.mapValues(_.flatten)`

Comment: Yup... that works in this case, but some times (specially for beginners) knowing why your code works is more important.

Comment: @pedrofurla the other one is even "uglier"