# Conversion of mutable collections to immutable introduces performance penalty

Tags: performance, scala, collections

I've encountered a strange behavior regarding conversion of mutable collections to immutable ones, which might significantly affect performance.

Let's take a look at the following code:

```scala
val map: Map[String, Set[Int]] = createMap()
while (true) {
    map.get("existing-key")
}
```

It simply creates a map once, and then repeatedly accesses one of its enries, which contains a set as a value. It may create the map in several ways:

With immutable collections:

```
def createMap() = keys.map(key => key -> (1 to amount).toSet).toMap
```

Or with mutable collections (note the two conversion options at the end):

```
def createMap() = {
    val map = mutable.Map[String, mutable.Set[Int]]()
    for (key <- keys) {
        val set = map.getOrElseUpdate(key, mutable.Set())
        for (i <- 1 to amount) {
            set.add(i)
        }
    }
    map.toMap.mapValues(_.toSet) // option #1
    map.mapValues(_.toSet).toMap // option #2
}
```

Curiously enough, mutable #1 code creates a map which invokes `toSet` on its values whenever `get` is invoked (if the entry exists), which may introduce a significant performance hit (depending on the use-case).

Why is this happening? How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`mapValues`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#mapValues[W](f:V=%3EW):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,W]) simply returns a **map view** which maps every key of this map to `f(this(key))`. The resulting map wraps the original map **without copying any elements**.

Looking at the implementation, `mapValues` returns an instance of `MappedValues` which override the [`get` function](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0/src/library/scala/collection/MapLike.scala#L257):

```
def get(key: K) = self.get(key).map(f)
```

If you want to force the materialization of the map, call `toMap` after the `mapValues` call. Just like you did in #2!

Comment: I guess one would wonder [why mapValues produces a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882642).